# Strange crash on a functionCall when button is tapped

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a problem with a crash report from fabric I don't get:

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  AppGone                     0x1000d2ae0 SignupViewController.goToNext() -> () (SignupViewController.swift)
1  AppGone                     0x1000d2b1c @objc SignupViewController.goToNext() -> () (SignupViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x18f0367b0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
3  UIKit                          0x18f036730 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
4  UIKit                          0x18f020be4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 452
5  UIKit                          0x18f03601c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584
6  UIKit                          0x18f035b44 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2484
7  UIKit                          0x18f030d8c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 2988
8  UIKit                          0x18f001858 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
9  UIKit                          0x18f7eecb8 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2736
10 UIKit                          0x18f7e8720 __handleEventQueue + 784
11 CoreFoundation                 0x189166278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
12 CoreFoundation                 0x189165bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1891637c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
14 CoreFoundation                 0x189092048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
15 GraphicsServices               0x18ab15198 GSEventRunModal + 180
16 UIKit                          0x18f06c628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
17 UIKit                          0x18f067360 UIApplicationMain + 208
18 AppGone                     0x100045070 main (AppDelegate.swift:22)
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1880745b8 (Missing)

--

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  AppGone                     0x1000d2ae0 SignupViewController.goToNext() -> () (SignupViewController.swift)
1  AppGone                     0x1000d2b1c @objc SignupViewController.goToNext() -> () (SignupViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x18f0367b0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
3  UIKit                          0x18f036730 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
4  UIKit                          0x18f020be4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 452
5  UIKit                          0x18f03601c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584
6  UIKit                          0x18f035b44 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2484
7  UIKit                          0x18f030d8c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 2988
8  UIKit                          0x18f001858 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
9  UIKit                          0x18f7eecb8 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2736
10 UIKit                          0x18f7e8720 __handleEventQueue + 784
11 CoreFoundation                 0x189166278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
12 CoreFoundation                 0x189165bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1891637c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
14 CoreFoundation                 0x189092048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
15 GraphicsServices               0x18ab15198 GSEventRunModal + 180
16 UIKit                          0x18f06c628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
17 UIKit                          0x18f067360 UIApplicationMain + 208
18 AppGone                     0x100045070 main (AppDelegate.swift:22)
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1880745b8 (Missing)

#1. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188186a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824936c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248db4 start_wqthread + 4

#2. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188186a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824936c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248db4 start_wqthread + 4

#3. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18816816c mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188167fdc mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x189165cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x189163908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x189092048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  Foundation                     0x189ba0b1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x189bc160c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7  UIKit                          0x18f9e1c7c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x189c9e50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b860 _pthread_body + 240
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b770 _pthread_body + 282
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248dbc thread_start + 4

#4. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188186a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824936c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248db4 start_wqthread + 4

#5. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  AppGone                     0x1002e7430 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4297913392
1  AppGone                     0x1002e7430 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4297913392
2  AppGone                     0x1002e72ec CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4297913068
3  AppGone                     0x1002d7a9c CLSHandler + 4297849500
4  AppGone                     0x1002d2a40 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4297828928
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b860 _pthread_body + 240
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b770 _pthread_body + 282
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248dbc thread_start + 4

#6. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18816816c mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188167fdc mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x189165cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x189163908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x189092048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  CFNetwork                      0x18987fcec +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
6  Foundation                     0x189c9e50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b860 _pthread_body + 240
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b770 _pthread_body + 282
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248dbc thread_start + 4

#7. GAIThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18816816c mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188167fdc mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x189165cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x189163908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x189092048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  Foundation                     0x189ba0b1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x189bf52a0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7  AppGone                     0x1002b2fac +[GAI threadMain:] + 4297699244
8  Foundation                     0x189c9e50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b860 _pthread_body + 240
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b770 _pthread_body + 282
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248dbc thread_start + 4

#8. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188185e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824a9d0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x187b753ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d93a548 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 112
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d93a4bc bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 168
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d93a39c std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<std::__1::mutex, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::mutex> >::~__shared_ptr_emplace() + 10
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d93a64c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 92
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b860 _pthread_body + 240
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b770 _pthread_body + 282
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248dbc thread_start + 4

#9. com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18816816c mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188167fdc mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x189165cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x189163908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x189092048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1890df8d4 CFRunLoopRun + 112
6  CoreMotion                     0x18feda7dc (null) + 187376
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b860 _pthread_body + 240
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824b770 _pthread_body + 282
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248dbc thread_start + 4

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188186a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188249188 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248db4 start_wqthread + 4

#11. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188186a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18824936c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188248db4 start_wqthread + 4
```

When I go the goToNext method it only contains this code:

```
 SVProgressHUD.show()
        let selectedRow = self.pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        let profileId = self.profiles[selectedRow].id
        RemoteServiceFactory.serviceCall().updateUser(profileId) { (result, error) in
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            if let _ = error {
                self.showErrorWithMessage("error")
            } else {
                self.goToNextStep(self.profiles[selectedRow])
            }
        }
```

When I test this it just works. I don't see how it can crash.

It's also weird that there is a @objc goToNext method because I declared it without the @objc.

Somebody knows more about this?

EDIT:

I tested that the callback is back on the main thread via

```
if NSThread.isMainThread() { print("Main Thread") }
```

So it can't be the problem that the hud is dismissed.

Comment: I'll guess that the @objc is implied because your class inherits from NSObject.  Is there a message in the crash report that suggests a reason...invalid address or anything?

Comment: No not that I see. I really don't get it.

Comment: The method can probably crash when there is nothing selected?

Comment: if  RemoteServiceFactory.serviceCall() is a call to a backend service then its completionHandler is not really on the mainThread is it is an async method

Answer (score 1):

try to dismiss SVProgressHUD.dismiss() on the MainThread since you are dimissing it in background now and the  HUD interactions in general have to be done in MainThread

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue {
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
 })
```

Comment: The callback is on Thread 1 so it is on the main thread. I don't think this is the problem right?

Comment: i suggest you should try this ... I have had the same error and this solved it

Comment: Really? Because I tested with if NSThread.isMainThread() { print("Main Thread") } that I'm on the main thread.

Comment: sometimes it doesn't let you know...just try

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your callback happens after the view controller is out of memory.

Whenever you make an asynchronous call, you should convert self to weak self.

```
 SVProgressHUD.show()
    let selectedRow = self.pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    let profileId = self.profiles[selectedRow].id
    RemoteServiceFactory.serviceCall().updateUser(profileId) { [weak self] (result, error) in

        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        guard let weakSelf = self else { return }

        if error != nil {
            weakSelf.showErrorWithMessage("error")
        } else {
            weakSelf.goToNextStep(weakSelf[selectedRow])
        }
    }
```